# SQLAlchemy doesn't let me set up Flask apps multiple times in a test fixture

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am writing a [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) application that uses [SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/) for its database backend.

The Flask application is created with an app factory called `create_app`.

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app(config_filename = None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    if config_filename is None:
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        app.config.from_mapping(config_filename)

    from .model import db
    db.init_app(app)
    db.create_all(app=app)

    return app
```

The database model consists of a single object called `Document`.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Document(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    document_uri = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True)
```

I am using [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) to do unit testing. I create a pytest [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html) called `app_with_documents` that calls the application factory to create an application and adds some `Document` objects to the database before the test is run, then empties out the database after the unit test has completed.

```
import pytest
from model import Document, db
from myapplication import create_app

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    config = {
        'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': f"sqlite:///:memory:",
        'TESTING': True,
        'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS': False
    }
    app = create_app(config)
    yield app
    with app.app_context():
        db.drop_all()

@pytest.fixture
def app_with_documents(app):
    with app.app_context():
        document_1 = Document(document_uri='Document 1')
        document_2 = Document(document_uri='Document 2')
        document_3 = Document(document_uri='Document 3')
        document_4 = Document(document_uri='Document 4')
        db.session.add_all([document_1, document_2, document_3, document_4])
        db.session.commit()
    return app
```

I have multiple unit tests that use this fixture.

```
def test_unit_test_1(app_with_documents):
    ...

def test_unit_test_2(app_with_documents):
    ...
```

If I run a single unit test everything works. If I run more than one test, subsequent unit tests crash at the `db.session.commit()` line in the test fixture setup with "no such table: document".

```
    def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
E       sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: document [SQL: 'INSERT INTO document (document_uri) VALUES (?)'] [parameters: ('Document 1',)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

What I expect is that each unit test gets its own brand-new identical prepopulated database so that all the tests would succeed.

(This is an issue with the database tables, not the unit tests. I see the bug even if my unit tests consist of just `pass`.)

The fact that the error message mentions a missing table makes it look like the `db.create_all(app=app)` in `create_app` is not being called after the first unit test runs. However, I have verified in the debugger that this application factory function is called once for every unit test as expected.

It is possible that my call to `db.drop_all()` is an incorrect way to clear out the database. So instead of an in-memory database, I tried creating one on disk and then deleting it as part of the test fixture cleanup. (This is the technique [recommended](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/#the-testing-skeleton) in the Flask documentation.)

```
@pytest.fixture
def app():
    db_fd, db_filename = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.sqlite')
    config = {
        'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': f"sqlite:///{db_filename}",
        'TESTING': True,
        'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS': False
    }
    yield create_app(config)
    os.close(db_fd)
    os.unlink(db_filename)
```

This produces the same error.

- Is this a bug in Flask and/or SQLAlchemy?
- What is the correct way to write Flask test fixtures that prepopulate an application's database?

This is Flask 1.0.2, Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.3.2, and pytest 3.6.0, which are all the current latest versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my `conftest.py` I was importing the contents of `model.py` in my application like so.

```
from model import Document, db
```

I was running the unit tests in Pycharm using Pycharm's pytest runner. If instead I run tests from the command line with `python -m pytest` I see the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
ERROR: could not load /Users/wmcneill/src/FlaskRestPlus/test/conftest.py
```

I can get my tests running from the command line by fully-qualifying the import path in `conftest.py`.

```
from myapplication.model import Document, db
```

When I do this all the unit tests pass. They also pass when I run the unit tests from inside Pycharm.

So it appears that I had incorrectly written an import statement in my unit tests. However, when I ran those unit tests via Pycharm, instead of seeing an error message about the import, the scripts launched but then had weird SQL errors.

I still haven't figured out why I saw the strange SQL errors I did. Presumably something subtle about the way global state is being handled. But changing the import line fixes my problem.